# SQL Server - Query with tricky where clause

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a report where user can select one filter value amongst these three and can pass a date range ('From Date' and 'To Date') before clicking the submit button:

1. Events within Date Range
2. New Guests within Date Range
3. New Guests Beyond Date Range

I want to fire a select query on **myTable** for the selected filter value.

If user selects first value (1), the query should give all the records where dtEventDate is between the date range that is entered.

If user selects second value (2), the query should give all the records where dtGuestCreatedDate is between the date range that is entered.

Similarly, If user selects third value (3), the query should give all the records where dtGuestCreatedDate is greater than 'To Date'.

My query would be like,

```
Select * from myTable
where
if '#filterValue#'='Events within Date Range'
then myTable.dtEventDate between '' and ''
else if '#filterValue#'='New Guests withing Date Range'
then myTable.dtGuestCreatedDate between '' and ''
else myTable.dtGuestCreatedDate > ''
```

I dont know how do I write this condition.

I have this so far that would give me events within date range:

```
select * from myTable
where myTable.dtEventDate between
case when '#filterValue#'='Events Within Date Range' then '10/01/2016' end
and '11/30/2016'
```

But I need to check all the three filter values in one where clause.

Can anybody help please?

Comment: Which programming language do you use? You should dynamically build your `WHERE` condition depending on the filter value the user has selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this based on the example that you gave:

```
Select * from myTable
where
    ('#filterValue#'='Events within Date Range' AND myTable.dtEventDate between '' and '')
    OR
    ('#filterValue#'='New Guests withing Date Range' AND myTable.dtGuestCreatedDate between '' and '')
    OR
    ('#filterValue#'='New Guests Beyond Date Range' AND myTable.dtGuestCreatedDate > '')
```

Comment: Great! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from myTable
where case @filtervalue
    when 'Events within daterange' then myTable.dtEventDate between ...
    when 'New Guests within daterange' then ...
    ...
    end
```

Also, I would strongly recommend that you use *parameterized queries* to avoid SQL injection attacks. Assuming your environment permits that.

Comment: That throws an error - Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'between'

Comment: The ... is just a placeholder for whatever condition you want to put there. Basically after then **when** keyword you can put any boolean condition that you may want to check. Logically equivalent to Jakub's answer, just a little less to type.

Comment: Works fine for me on postgres - don't have SQL Server to test on.